# java.lang.module.FindException: Module commons.math3 not found, required by org.apache.poi.poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I ran into a problem while developing the application.
I used the Gradle with the next dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.36.0.2")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.0")
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.1')
    implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.4.2') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}
```

Problem:

```
> Task :MainApplication.main() FAILED
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module SparseBitSet not found, required by org.apache.poi.poi

Execution failed for task ':MainApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.2/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

and

```
> Task :MainApplication.main() FAILED
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module commons.math3 not found, required by org.apache.poi.poi

Execution failed for task ':MainApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.2/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

After this i changed dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:1.2")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1")
    implementation("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.36.0.2")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.0")
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.1')
    implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.4.2') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}
```

But it didn't solve the problem

I have not any ideas to slove it
Hope you can help me with it.

Comment: SparseBitSet and commons-math3 are old jars and don't have java module info set up - maybe you can trying running with `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-gradle-example runs for me with Java 17 and there is no requirement to set any module parameters

Comment: It's possible to run without a module but when it is necessary, it became a problem.